# Struggling with definite/indefinite article usage in French

Tags: articles-definis

I wrote this phrase in an online course:

```
"En faisant du velo je regardais des paysages."
```

However the teacher insisted on using `les` instead of `des`. But in fact I did not want to express the notion of seeing "the landscapes".
Could someone explain to me (in French or English) when and why would I use the definite or indefinite article in such a phrase?

Comment: It would be easier to say if you told us exactly what your idea was in English. That said, in general,  for this non-possessive usage, the des would be some, as in: J'ai vu **des chats** dans la rue. I saw some cats in the street. Now, if the idea is: En faisant du velo en France l'été dernier, je vu des paysages incroyables. des would work: *some incredible landscapes*. Otherwise, for a single cycling event, le paysage. You need either un or le there.

Comment: C'est bien de savoir que je ne suis pas la seule à avoir ce genre de problèmes. :)

Comment: More notes: @Greg Think of this way: In English, when you say I saw cats in the street, that is a general idea. Except here's the trick, in French, you need an article. You can't say: J'ai vu chats dans la rue. So, you rule out: a cat (un chat), and the cats/the cat (les chats). So, it must be des chats for "the cats". Now, it can be translated as some, but it can also be translated as just: cats.  In French, you will always need an article, no matter what. In English, we have the plural which allows us to not use an article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In French, we say *je regarde **le** paysage* because there is only one *paysage* to see. We do not say *je regarde **un** paysage* unless maybe if you are talking about paintings<sup>1</sup>.

When referring to a trip, you can still use the singular:

> *En faisant du vélo, je regardais le paysage.*

It would work even if the *paysage* changed but if you want to explicitly say that you saw various landscapes, *je regardais **les** paysages (variés qui s'offraient à mes yeux)* would indeed be the idiomatic way.

*Des paysages* is possible if you are talking about specific landscapes:

> *En faisant du vélo, je voyais défiler des paysages familiers.*

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You can also use *un paysage* if what this *paysage* is unspecified, e.g. *Quand je regarde un paysage, je ne peux m'empêcher d'en voir tous les défauts* ("When I look at a landscape I cannot help seeing all its defects." Oscar Wilde)</sub>

Comment: Et si, par exemple, je roule trop rapidement, et que je regarde surtout devant moi, le sentier, est-il possible de dire _Je regarde **des** paysages_ si je veux souligner que je ne prête attention qu'à certains paysages, que je ne relève la tête qu'occasionnellement ? Ou que je contemple certains paysages, ceux que je trouve les plus beaux ?

Comment: @Oreste Pas vraiment. Ce serait plutôt: *Des temps en temps, je regarde le paysage* mais le pluriel pourrait être utilisé dans une phrase comme celle que je viens d'ajouter à ma réponse.

Comment: _Pas vraiment._ OK. Mais pourquoi ma proposition n'est pas bonne ? Parce qu'elle n'est pas idiomatique et que les gens ne parlent pas de la sorte ? Pourtant, ma logique devrait être bonne, non ?

Comment: Thank you. To be frank it's not intuitive for me at all, I guess I will have to learn it by heart:/

Comment: @Oreste C'est un peu comme l'expression *regarder l'heure* ou *regarder le ciel*. Tu peux dire, *quand je voyage, je regarde souvent l'heure* ou *je regarde le ciel de temps en temps*. L'heure va forcément changer, et le ciel probablement, mais on n'emploie pas le pluriel et encore moins l'article défini. On peux éventuellement dire, *je regarde les heures qui défilent* mais *je regarde des heures* ou *je regarde des ciels* sont encore plus exclus que *je regarde des paysages*.